# Selenium with Angular - XPath how to get to elements when $index present?

Tags: python-3.x, angular, forms, selenium, webdriver

Using Python 3.7 with Selenium on pages that include Angular, please advise how to best locate an element such as this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].lseCatTy" value="FEDERAL" ng-disabled="!section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].editable" ng-class="classes(&#39;lseCatTy&#39;)" ng-change="section3.updateLseCatTy($index, section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].lseCatTy)" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse" name="759" style="">
```

or this

```
<button type="button" uib-tooltip="Edit" tooltip-placement="right" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="section3.data.editContainer($index);" ng-disabled="editingDrilling1 || submissionTypeSR">
```

when it exists in blocks such as the following. What's tripping me up is the $index... The page has multiple `fieldset` tags and that number is DYNAMIC... For example, a user can add more of one type of the `fieldset` while editing the page- but only this one type.

```
<div ng-if="section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId != null &amp;&amp; section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId != &#39;&#39;" class="ng-scope" style="">
    <!-- ngRepeat: wellFeature in section3.data.generalSection3.container track by $index -->
    <div ng-repeat="wellFeature in section3.data.generalSection3.container track by $index" class="ng-scope">
        <!-- ngIf: section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].deleteSegmentLocation == null -->
        <fieldset class="legend-border ng-scope" ng-if="section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].deleteSegmentLocation == null">
            <legend/>
            <div class="col-lg-12 panel panel-default">
                <div class="row panel-heading ng-binding">
                            SHL <br>
                        <!-- ngIf: section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].legBHLAttr == 'PPP' -->
                        <!-- ngIf: section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].legBHLAttr != 'PPP' && section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].legBHLAttr != 'SHL' -->
                        <!-- ngIf: section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].legBHLAttr == 'SHL' -->
                        <div ng-if="section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].legBHLAttr == &#39;SHL&#39;" class="ng-scope"/>
                        <!-- end ngIf: section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].legBHLAttr == 'SHL' -->
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-11">
                        <!-- ngIf: section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId=='1'|| section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId=='3' || section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId=='2' || section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId=='4' -->
                        <div ng-if="section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId==&#39;1&#39;|| section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId==&#39;3&#39; || section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId==&#39;2&#39; || section3.data.generalSection3.srvyTyId==&#39;4&#39;" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;" class="ng-scope">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="required-field">Lease Type</label>
                                        <br>
                                            <div ng-class="classes(&#39;lseCatTy&#39;+&#39;,&#39;+$index.toString(), [])">
                                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                                    <input type="radio" ng-model="section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].lseCatTy" value="FEDERAL" ng-disabled="!section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].editable" ng-class="classes(&#39;lseCatTy&#39;)" ng-change="section3.updateLseCatTy($index, section3.data.generalSection3.container[$index].lseCatTy)" class="ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse" name="759" style=""> Federal
                                                    </label>
                                                    <label class="radio-inline">
```

What I have working is:

```
self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@ng-click='section3.data.editContainer($index);']"))).click()
```

And this gets the first instance of that button (in the top fieldset), but I don't know how to get an arbitrary instance of it.

Comment: You mean accessing the `input` element which has `$[index]`?

Comment: @supputuri Yes, as is shown in the top code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned to navigate the DOM using parent elements and finding elements within parent elements --

This became a matter of finding a unique parent (lines 1 and 2), then finding the edit button for that section (line 3), and finding the desired element (line 4).

```
shl_div = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='row panel-heading ng-binding' and contains(text(),'SHL')]")))
shl_par = shl_div.find_element_by_xpath("..")
shl_par.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@ng-click='section3.data.editContainer($index);']").click()
shl_par.find_element_by_xpath(".//input[@value='FEDERAL']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[ng-model*="$index"],[ng-click*="$index"]')`

Comment: That works to get a set of elements; however, finding the element in question is eluding me. E.g. the set contains 125 elements when I look for value="FEDERAL" 

I don't see how to uniquely identify an element if there isn't something in the element itself that's unique... or how would I find the 1 out of 125 therein?

Comment: Ideal to identify the element when included in a div like this one: <div class="row panel-heading ng-binding"> SHL <br>